# Boost posix time

Tags: boost, time, posix

I have a very strange problem now.

```
class Message
{
  Field time;
  void SetTimeStamp()
  {
    time.dataTimeValue = &boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();
  }
  void SetOtherFields()
  {
  }
};

class Field
{
  boost::posix::ptime* dateTimeValue;
};

int main()
{
  Message myMessage;
  myMessage.SetTimeStamp();
  myMessage.SetOtherFields();
}
```

When I call `myMessage.SetTimeStamp()`, I can set the TimeStamp correctly, I can see the address of `dateTimeValue` and the Value makes sense. But after that, I call `myMessage.SetOtherFields()`, the `dateTimeValue` pointer still points to the same memory which is good, but the value in that memory changes to a carzy number. I don't know what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A decent compiler should have warned that the code is taking address of temporary.  The [`microsec_clock::local_time()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html) function returns `ptime` by value, resulting in `Message::SetTimeStamp` storing the address of the temporary into `Field::dateTimeValue`.  Trying to access the values of the memory will result in undefined behavior.

To resolve this, consider changing `Field` to aggregate a `boost::posix::ptime` member variable, rather than a pointer.

```cpp
class Field
{
public:
  boost::posix_time::ptime dateTimeValue;
};

class Message
{
public:
  Field time;
  void SetTimeStamp()
  {
    time.dataTimeValue = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();
  }
};
```